# Maven creates an empty Pom.xml

Tags: maven-3

I'm trying to create Maven Project.

File - New Project - Maven. Archetype do not indicate.

Then everything is standard: GroupId and ArtifactId. The project is created with empty Pom.xml

[image]

Java installed:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Maven installed:

```
 mvn -version
 Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-
 04T01:39:06+06:00)
 Maven home: D:\Apache_Maven\bin\..
 Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
 Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're seeing an empty `pom.xml`.

I can however offer an alternate solution:

- Use the [maven quickstart](http://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) archetype (maybe from command line)
- Import the resulting pom.xml into your project / create new project from the generated pom.xml.

Comment: The most interesting that the problem appeared after upgrading JDK. Was the version JDK jdk1.8.0_141, then updated to version jdk1.8.0_144. After this update and started dancing with a tambourine. Rolled back to version jdk1.8.0_141 eliminated all the problems. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

1. your maven path is set correctly
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm
2. run mvn --version and check if your maven is pointing to write jdk as well
3. IF these two things set correctly while creating project " archetype" list show show . if it is still not showing that means there is a problem in your setup and maven will still show old version
4. ALso check Proejct->setting->Build deployment &Execution->maven shows correct path